# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:include-filter'

Tags: spring

**Spring Filter components in auto scanning**
the below xml gives error, it says no declaration can be found for element 'context:include-filter'.
everything seems fine to me.
using spring 3.0 release

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">



    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="ComponentFiltering" />

    <context:include-filter type="regex"
        expression="ComponentFiltering.Data.*Dat.*" />

</beans>
```

Comment: Your xlm is wrong, which is also what the error is telling you. The `include-filter` should go inside the `component-scan` tag as it isn't a top-level tag.